# How to render formatted data to html in Python Flask Framwork?

Tags: jquery, python, html, mongodb, flask

I have some formatted data in MongoDB, named i:

```
<p><strong>some string</strong></p>
```

But when I render it with `flask` and `jinjia`, like:

```
{% for i in example %}
    <div>{{ i }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The **Browser** show me:

`<p><strong>some string</strong></p>`

But I want to just get:

**some string**

I do it using ajax and put the formatted data in html, using jQuery `html()` method.

But how can I do it just in template rendering part?

Comment: It would really help to see your code here. A github url would suffice. Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried the `safe` filter? http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja2 escapes html by default. To mark data as safe for printing as html, use the [`safe`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#controlling-autoescaping) filter.

Either like this:

```
{{ myvariable|safe }}
```

Or turn escaping off for a block:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    <p>autoescaping is disabled here
    <p>{{ will_not_be_escaped }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Flask depends on Jinja by default, but you can use a different template engine if you please, but Jinja still needs to be installed.

More information:

- [Jinja2 Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/)
- [Flask Templating](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/)

Comment: It really helps, thank you. Before your answer, I thought the problem was caused by `flask` framework.

Comment: It's easy to confuse them, I added some links to my answer for future reference.